# How can I change monitor settings to duplicate and extend via script

Tags: c#, settings, multiple-monitors, screens, monitors

As I am using a laptop with a tv as its second monitor I want to make a little script which will trigger screen settings from extended to clone and when it is set to clone it should set the screen settings to extended. I want to make it in c# as it is my primary language and I think it could solve my problem.

So i have made a console application like this for now:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DisplayChanger.Start();
    }

    private static Process DisplayChanger = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "DisplaySwitch.exe",
            Arguments = "/extend"
        }
    };
}
```

It works fine creating a new process. But my question is, how can I check what status the "displays" have? I need that so i can run a test to see what process to start.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Is this a programming exercise, or are you just trying to solve the issue? If you just want a solution, I've dealt with this two ways: 1) If you are using Win7, the Windows Key-P combo does just this. 2) I have an AutoHotkey script (that I cribbed from somewhere else) from back in the days of Win XP

Comment: Programming exercise is not the word for this. I'm just trying to make a task simpler than it is right now, by having a program in the desktop i can just open to extend the screen if it is set to dual and vice verca

Comment: C# solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462742/1265105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a programming solution, but you should check out [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/).  It provides either shortcuts or hotkeys to change display settings for multiple monitors plus gives you tons of other features essential for working with multiple monitors.

[image]

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) does this too, but isn't updated nearly as much.  I used to use UltraMon for years but more recently switched to DisplayFusion.