# Can Windows 11 Sound and Display settings be scripted?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-11, windows-scripting

I'm helping a user with a personal Windows 11 computer which, in addition to the built-in monitor, is connected via HDMI to a shared/public television display.

When it comes time to stream a show or movie to the larger display, the following two operations must occur:

1. Start > Settings > System > Sound > Output > Select correct device from dropdown list.
2. Start > Settings > System > Display > Set display mode to "Extend" > Confirm changes.

Then, when steaming time is over, the Sound and Display settings must be set back to the more private configuration:

1. Start > Settings > System > Sound > Output > Select built-in monitor from dropdown list.
2. Start > Settings > System > Display > Set display mode to "Duplicate" > Confirm changes.

This "works" in that it produces the desired outcome, but is not "workable" for the non-technical user, given the number of touch points and values to remember. What would be great would be a pair of functionally equivalent scripts (one for each workflow) that I could link to as Desktop shortcuts.

Assuming full administrator access, is such a thing possible? Is there any API documentation I should be searching?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275063/extend-my-windows-desktop-onto-this-monitor-programmatically

Comment: aaaand https://superuser.com/questions/1054594/switching-default-audio-device-with-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For display devices, Windows comes with a built-in command-line program `displayswitch.exe` (though do note [that Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275063/extend-my-windows-desktop-onto-this-monitor-programmatically) and [Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1036148/displayswitch-exe-behavior-on-windows-11-22h2) have different, and incompatible, command-line options).

For audio output, Windows doesn't seem to have a built-in command-line program nor PowerShell cmdlet, [but NirSoft provides a reputable command-line program: `nircmd setdefaultsounddevice`](https://superuser.com/questions/1054594/switching-default-audio-device-with-a-batch-file).

So combine the two:

**Start Streaming.cmd**

```
REM For Windows 11:
REM DisplaySwitch.exe 1 = Internal
REM DisplaySwitch.exe 2 = Clone
REM DisplaySwitch.exe 3 = Extend
REM DisplaySwitch.exe 4 = External

DisplaySwitch.exe 3

nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Desired output device name" 1
```

**Stop Streaming.cmd**

```
DisplaySwitch.exe 1

nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Desired original output device name" 1
```